# JS: Search/Replace JSON information with information from another JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

So let's say I have a JSON file that I pull from a server that returns some abstracted information.

```
"MissionInfo": {
    "missionType": "MT_CAPTURE",
    "faction": "FC_CORPUS",
    "location": "SolNode97"
}
```

And I have a separate set of JSON files that have information on the shortcodes for each one of these. As an example, if looking for location...

`./reference/node-locations.json`

```
    {
        "mission_type": "MT_INTEL",
        "name": "amelthea",
        "node_id": "SolNode97",
        "planet_id": 7
    },
```

How would I go about checking the location, finding the same node_id in a separate file, then returning the name related to this particular value? As in, returning `amelthea` for a location. Is there a particular way to search through another JSON file accurately and quickly? Libraries/techniques?

Some clarification as the duplicate marking doesn't help - saw that post before.

While I can search for a key/value pair in the other files without a problem, I'm not sure how to do this smoothly while keeping things performant. Using ReactJS, if that helps things at all. Keeping everything in state on the main app.js. How exactly would I take an input, search for a key/value pair that matches it, then return a different key/value pair at the same level as what was returned?

Comment: What is the type of data in both files, array or simple object?

Comment: Also, how deep is the data tree in node-locations? If this is shallow (1 level only), I really think normal loop is more than enough

Comment: Objects for both files in this case!

Comment: `node-locations.json` looks like an array.

Comment: And unfortunately, the files are pretty huge. Mission info is about 6 levels deep so I figured a standard search may kill performance :c